# Unix diff with custom line separator

Tags: csv, unix, diff

Looking to compare two CSV files. Suppose the field separator is $, each record has two fields, and the file can be formatted something like:

```
a$simple line$
b$run-on-
line$
c$simple line$
```

Is there some switch or variety of Unix diff command that will let me run the comparison where the record separator (line separator) is the $ sign immediately followed by a new line?

Ideally I want to be guaranteed that diff outputs the entire record when any change is detected.

With the default behavior, I could potentially get a partial record as diff output (in scenarios where the record runs over several lines).

Is there some smarter way to do this that I'm not considering?

--
Edited to add: sample of expected output

If I compared the CSV file above with:

```
a$simple line$
b$run-on-changed-
line$
c$simple line$
```

... I would want to see the entire record b reported as a difference. Something like

```
2c2
< b$run-on-\nline$
---
> b$run-on-changed-\nline$
```

Comment: Could you provide examples of expected output?

Comment: Edited to add example of expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter, there is no direct support of custom line separator in gnu diff: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html (gnu diffutils)

You may try to use `sed` twice: sed to convert your format to one-record-per-line for diffing; diff converted files; sed back to multiline record format.

First sed will convert all `$\n` to real `\n`; and `\n` without `$` before it to some unique special sequence, like `#%#$%#$%#$#`.

Then do diff.

Second sed will convert `#%#$%#$%#$#` back to `\n` (or to `\\n` to easier viewing of diff output)

Answer (score 1):

There are diff variants which support working with csv. Some of them may handle csv with line breaks inside fields:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csvdiff (python)

> csvdiff allows you to compare the semantic contents of two CSV files, ignoring things like row and column ordering in order to get to what’s actually changed. This is useful if you’re comparing the output of an automatic system from one day to the next, so that you can look at just what’s changed.

https://github.com/agardiner/csv-diff  (ruby)

> Unlike a standard diff that compares line by line, and is sensitive to the ordering of records, CSV-Diff identifies common lines by key field(s), and then compares the contents of the fields in each line.

http://csvdiff.sourceforge.net/ (perl)

> csvdiff is a perl script to compare/diff two (comma) seperated files with each other. The part that is different to standard diff is, that you'll get the number of the record where the difference occours and the field/column which is different. The separator can be set to the value you want it to, not just comma. Also you can to provide a third file which contains the columnnames in one(!) line separated by your separator.